# I can store a function in an object in a mongoDB within the mongo shell but not within the node.js driver

Tags: function, mongodb, shell, driver, store

```
var f=function(x){return x*x}
var a={a:1, f:f}
var b = db.test.findOne({a:1})
call b.f(5) --> 25 // works fine within the mongo shell
```

---

I can't do the same within the node.js driver.
Even attempting to get the above object within the node.js driver. Console.log from node.js driver shows that it is stored like this :

```
{ _id: 5267ffd0ef117eab24aa6d73,
  a: 1,
  f:
   { _bsontype: 'Code',
     code: 'function (x){return x*x}',
     scope: {}
   } 
}
```

**How can I call that function from the node.js driver?** 
A call like :

```
 db.collection('test').findOne({a:1}, function(err, b) {
        console.log(b.f(5));  ---> call of function f does not work.
        db.close();
  });
```

throws the error : Property 'f' of object # is not a function